# Reading a text with ->read() and showing it in console

Tags: c++, console, c++-cli

I got a tutorial book with an excercise to basically copy a txt file with using the read() method. And there this is not a problem using the following code:

```
while (inputfile->Peek() != -1)
{
    input= inputfile->Read();
    outputfile->Write(input);
}
```

But now I wanted to show the content of the txt file on console, using:
    Console::Write(input);
And all I get is numbers (probably unicode: (84104105115....)
The excercise book shows in it's solution that the input variable should be a "char" and that input= inputfile->Read(); should be input= (char) inputfile->Read(); instead. But as far as I see it, it does not make any difference if "input" is int or char, or if I use the convert via (char). The Console always shows numbers, and the copied file is always correct.
I guess that ->Write() and ->Read() work perfectly with unicode as input, but Console::Write() doesn't.
Can anyone clarify on this and show me the probably pretty easy solution to express the file on the console after it was read with Read()? (with readline I have no problems, I am working on understanding this, not necessarily finding the best solution).

the complete code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
int input;
StreamReader ^inputfile = gcnew StreamReader("text.txt");
StreamWriter ^outputfile = gcnew StreamWriter("textkopie.txt");
while (inputfile->Peek() != -1)
{
    input= inputfile->Read();
    Console::Write(input);
    outputfile->Write(input);
}
inputfile->Close();
outputfile->Close();


Console::ReadLine();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this on the Macintosh or on a Playstation?

Comment: I don't recognise this as std library streams. whay library is this?

Comment: It looks like C++/CLI on .NET

Answer (score 0):

inputfile and outputfile are structs and I don't think function peek(),write(),read() are its members? please post your struct declaration. Correct me if i'm my idea is wrong.

Comment: Just added all the code, as I am unsure what exactly you were asking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library's you are using so I cannot dive into to much detail. However, by looking over your code/question I'd say:

```
int input;
Console::Write(input);
```

Will always print numbers, because input is declared as an it. If you read a char into input, it will automatically be cast to an int.

If you want to print a char, you need:

```
char input;
Console::Write(input);
```

This link might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write.aspx

Comment: Does not make a difference. Neither on console (numbers), nor in the file (letters). Even with input= (char)inputfile->Read(); it doesn't change a thing